# How to accurately order the clusters based on color in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, k-means

I have an image of leaf that has mostly three colors black background, green leaf and brown diseased spots. 
Here is the image

[image: input image]

When I cluster it first time, I get brown spots in cluster 1, green portion in cluster 2, black region in cluster 3(for example).

When I cluster it second time, I get green portion in cluster 1,brown spots in cluster 2, black region in cluster 3(for example). b

When I cluster it third time the order of clusters are different again.

I want to change the code such that the brown spots appear in cluster 1, green portion in cluster 2 and black in cluster 3. The order of clusters should be same even if I cluster many times.Could someone please help me with the code? I am using Matlab2009a. This question is about ordering clusters

Here is what is being done so far

```
function segmented_img = leaf_segmentation( original_img, nclusters )

original_img = im2double(original_img);
G=fspecial('gaussian',[200 250],1);
smoothed_img =imfilter(original_img,G,'same');

conversionform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_img = applycform(smoothed_img,conversionform);

ab_img = double(lab_img(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab_img,1);
ncols = size(ab_img,2);
ab_img = reshape(ab_img,nrows*ncols,2);

cluster_idx =   
kmeans(ab_img,nclusters,'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',3);
cluster_img = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
segmented_img = cell(1,nclusters);
for k = 1:nclusters
   segmented_img{k} = bsxfun( @times, original_img, cluster_img == k );
end


end


segmented = leaf_segmentation( imread('input image'), 3 );

figure,imshow(segmented{1}), title('Cluster 1');
figure, imshow(segmented{2}), title('Cluster 2');
figure, imshow(segmented{3}), title('Cluster 3');
```

Comment: K-means probably initializes randomly, so to get deterministic behaviour you need to control random number generation. Before running your code, set the random seed to any specific value. See [this link](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) for documentation.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama this is a different question, I am asking how to order the clusters here . " How to accurately classify leafs into its disease category"  was not about ordering. Moreover that question doesn't have any answer. Please remove duplicate flag because this question is different and I genuinely need help.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab kmeans has a 'Start' parameter, which can be set to a matrix of centroid initial locations. You can initialize to black, brown and green and you will probably even get the results a bit faster, if the image is really mostly composed of these colours.

[Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)

Answer (score 0):

Just check the colors after the clustering!

One way of doing this is transforming the centroids color space to HSV and checking the values oh H and V.  H will give you the color (for example, around 120.0 degrees its green) and V will give you the "ligth", so if V is 0 then whatever H is, it is the black cluster.

This should be trivial to program, but dont hesitate to ask any questions about it.