# Making the "Region of Interest" (ROI) transparent in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've already made a function to cut out the image, and the part I cut out has a black background. I'm trying to make the black part transparent, then I can generate [an image sequence that I can create a video with](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/convert-between-image-sequences-and-video.html). I've tried converting the image to a double and then replacing the 0 values with NaN:

```
J = imread('imgExample.jpg');
J2 = im2double(J);
J2(J2 == 0) = NaN;
imwrite(J2, 'newImg.jpg');
```

but when I convert it into a video, it doesn't seem to stay. Is there any way to get the black part of the image to be transparent?

[image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959756/how-to-accurately-order-the-clusters-based-on-color-in-matlab]

Comment: Hi Mia, it's still not clear what you're trying to do. Maybe if you included a picture in your question? But in general, I don't think matlab videos support transparency; if by transparent you mean you want an axes object behind your 'j' one to be visible, then the answer is you need to create your video by using `getframe`, and the pixels should be made to have the exact values you want them to display (i.e. not nans). If you want a video that has a transparent "hole" in it such that when you play the video you can see your desktop through the hole, then that's much harder to achieve

Comment: Unable to give the exact picture but I'll find a good example, one sec

Comment: sorry, that doesn't really clarify much xD ... how do you envisage the end-result video? The leaf overlaid onto an independent background video? Also, from your explanation it sounds like what you call a ROI is actually the "background"? ... usually the ROI refers to the foreground, so this may be adding to my confusion

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou you're right about ROI, I'm talking about the background behind ROI, as in the black background. I might actually need the transparency.

Comment: I've used getFrame without success - it just returns 0s (black, I believe)

Comment: If there's any way to put values of NaN into a video, I think that's what I need, though I'm not sure if that is even possible.

Comment: please see my answer and comment there accordingly, I'll have a look at the specific nan question in the meantime :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123736/discussion-between-tasos-papastylianou-and-mia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From clarifications in comments, you are trying to create a *video* format that supports alpha transparency using matlab.

In general this seems impossible using matlab alone (at least in matlab 2013 which is the version I use). If you'd like to check if the newest matlab supports videos with alpha transparency, type `doc videowriter` and have a look at the available formats. If you see anything with transparency options there, take it from there. But the most I see on mine is 24bit RGB videos (i.e. three channels, no transparency).

So matlab does not have the ability to produce native .avi video with alpha transparency.

However, note that this is a very rare video format anyway, and even if you *did* manage to produce such a video, you would still have to find a suitable viewer which supports playing videos with transparency!

It's therefore important for you to tell us your particular use-case because it may be you're actually trying to do something much simpler (which may or may not be solvable via matlab) (i.e. a case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

E.g. you may be trying to create a video with transparency for the web instead, like here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video

If this is the case, then I would recommend you attempting the method outlined there; you can create individual .png "frames" with transparency in matlab using the `imwrite` function. have a look at its documentation, particularly the section about png images and the 'Alpha' property. But beyond that, you'd need an external tool to combine them into a .webm file, since matlab doesn't seem to have a tool like that (at least none that I can see at a glance; there might be a 3rd-party toolkit if you look on the web).

Hope this helps.

Comment: One question though - what about png transparency?

Comment: I might have done something wrong but I got an error: Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts, not sure what this means

Comment: The cameraman.tif should be an inbuilt grayscale matlab image. I think it means you're using one that is rgb instead, possibly? Convert that into a grayscale image. In any case it doesn't matter, just use any image, all it does is rotate the colourmap to give the illusion of a changing background against your leaf

Comment: I like the effect - t's pretty cool, but I need transparency instead of a background